# How to find the transfer function F(w) for this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter, transfer-function, nodal-analysis

[image: Circuit]

Hi,

My book on analogue circuits has this question and I have been stuck  at it for the past three days or so. I am supposed to figure out the transfer function for the network as well as the cutoff frequency and the angle. I am just having hard times figuring out how to solve it. I tried nodal analysis and the two poles theory but I get a different result every time.

Here are the values for resistors and capacitor:
R1=R3=4.7KOHM, R2=10KHOM and C=4.7 nF

Comment: Try representing everything to the left of the capacitor as a Thevenin equivalent, and then seeing if you can figure it out.  If that solves your problem you probably want to go back and try nodal analysis again, just for practice at nodal analysis -- you can solve it either way, and it should be direct (if tedious) to do it using either nodal or mesh analysis.

Comment: Didn't you already handle this exact topology? ([calculate transfer function](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/408302/how-to-calculate-the-transfer-function)?)

Comment: @TimWescott as jonk said I have already tackled it in the link he mentioned, but I am trying to get a second opinion on it since my cutoff frequency is very high, in fact it's 27k rad/sec which is why I would love if someone really could solve it for me and gave me the H(w), w_c and the angle.

Comment: 27k rad/sec is right on the button.  Remember that a kilo ohm times a nano-farad is 1M rad/sec -- tune your intuition based on that.

Comment: @TimWescott idk I'm being slow now after being stuck on this for a few days. So I'd appreciate another and more obvious hint.

Comment: @Reddevil I gave it a shot.

Comment: Your confusion confuses me.  Let me reword that -- 27k rad/second **is exactly right** if you're rounding to two significant digits.  **Your math is probably fine**; whatever intuition is telling you that your math is wrong is what's flawed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm a little confused, since you asked a question earlier using the same topology and it appeared (I didn't actually verify) you worked it out, okay. So I'm going to just take it as granted that you want to see something else, other than you did beforehand.

I've taken your schematic (on left) and redrawn it (on right):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f16qcL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That may be more or less confusing to you. But you can "see" some familiar structures, at least. There's a resistor-resistor divider and a resistor-capacitor divider. It seems like there should be some way to leverage those structures to get an answer. So let's just go on automatic pilot for a moment and see if it provides anything.

The simplest, first. We can Thevenize \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ and the two voltage nodes related to the input voltage in this way:

$$\begin{align*}
V_\text{TH}&=\frac{V_\text{IN+}\cdot R_1+V_\text{IN-}\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\\\\
R_\text{TH}&=\frac{ R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}
\end{align*}$$

This leads to the following schematic, which I'll adjust a little:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIqeaB.png)</sup>

This ***looks*** at first as though it may have both helped and ***not*** helped. It's helped, because it looks really simple now. It's ***not*** helped so much, because now your input voltage source seems ***muddled***. But it will work out fine, as it turns out.

The output voltage is now simply \$V_\text{OUT}=V_\text{OUT+}-V_\text{OUT-}=V_\text{OUT+}-0\:\text{V}=V_\text{OUT+}\$. That's easier. But let's see what the transfer function looks like now:

$$\begin{align*}
V_\text{OUT} &= \left(V_\text{IN+}-V_\text{TH}\right)\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{s C}}{\left(R_3+R_\text{TH}\right)+\frac{1}{s C}}\\\\
&=\left(V_\text{IN+}-\frac{V_\text{IN+}\cdot R_1+V_\text{IN-}\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{s C\left(R_3+\frac{ R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\right)+1}\\\\
&=\frac{V_\text{IN+}\cdot R_1+V_\text{IN+}\cdot R_2-\left(V_\text{IN+}\cdot R_1+V_\text{IN-}\cdot R_2\right)}{R_1+R_2}\cdot\frac{1}{s C\left(R_3+\frac{ R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\right)+1}\\\\
&=\frac{V_\text{IN+}\cdot R_2-V_\text{IN-}\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\cdot\frac{1}{s C\left(R_3+\frac{ R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\right)+1}\\\\
&=\left(V_\text{IN+}-V_\text{IN-}\right)\cdot\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\cdot\frac{1}{s C\left(R_3+\frac{ R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\right)+1}\\\\
&=V_\text{IN}\cdot\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2+s C\left(R_1 R_2+R_1 R_3+R_2 R_3\right)}\\\\&\therefore\\\\
\frac{V_\text{OUT}}{V_\text{IN}}&=\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2+s C\left(R_1 R_2+R_1 R_3+R_2 R_3\right)}
\end{align*}$$

In standard notation, this is:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_\text{OUT}}{V_\text{IN}}&=\frac{\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}}{1+s C\frac{R_1 R_2+R_1 R_3+R_2 R_3}{R_1+R_2}}\\\\
&=\frac{\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}}{1+s C\left[\left(R_1\mid\mid R_2\right)+R_3\right]}
\end{align*}$$

It would be convenient at this point to define \$K=\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$ and \$\tau=C\left[\left(R_1\mid\mid R_2\right)+R_3\right]\$:

$$\frac{V_\text{OUT}}{V_\text{IN}}=\frac{K}{1+s\tau}$$

No surprise. A one-pole low-pass filter equation form, with voltage gain \$K\$. Here, \$K\$ is the voltage gain and it will be less than 1. This is, of course, due to the voltage divider that you saw earlier, composed of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$. And it is pretty clear, also, where the resistance part of \$\tau\$ comes from: \$R_3\$ plus the Thevenin divider resistance composed from \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$.

The value is \$\omega=\frac{1}{\tau}\approx 27\:\text{k}\frac{\text{rad}}{\text{s}}\$ as you'd worked out.

---

The above is just using your imagination, together with more prosaic tools, to reformulate the question and see if you can get *there*, from *here*. Turns out, you can. The point here is to keep a flexible mind and attack problems from whatever approach works better at the time.